# Vuejs cache issue , NPM Build not changing hash each time for SPA vuejs app on Production using Nginx

Tags: vue.js, npm, caching

We have vuejs version 2.6.40 app running as SPA using Laravel as backend API.
When we run command npm run build it generates files into dist/* using the same HASH each time for production build.

```
css/chunk-vendors.1a7cdba8.css
js/chunk-vendors.d2af6920.js
css/app.7ca97c3b.css
js/app.7c8415cc.js
```

**This same HASH creating a huge problem for browser cache, if this has new hash each time will solve vue js browser cache issue.**

our vue.config.js has following settgins

```
module.exports = {
lintOnSave: false,
productionSourceMap: false, 
}
```

Comment: Can you try to put filenameHashing: true in vue config and what is the full command for your npm run script? I think you may be using somekind of packager it may be causing the issue.

Comment: we use NPM RUN BUILD for build , for serve NPM RUN SERVE. we checked with  filenameHashing: true , still not working.

Comment: Can you share package.json's scripts part?

Comment: my file you can download from here https://gofile.io/d/cNrS95

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with what I though was this issue. However a new hash is only generated if the contents of an asset changes. In other words just rebuilding to dist without changes to your project source files won’t change all the hashes. If you change source css / js files you will notice that the hashes (some, not necessarily all) will change…

Further reading here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/

What could be causing your caching issue is that your index.html file is cached, and hence referencing your assets with previous hashes. Setting no-cache in your headers for index.html should help with that!